# Get Gridview Data in PDF Format in C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#

I want to convert the data of datagridview into PDF file . For Example if i press  button1 i should get the  datagridview data as pdf.

How can I do this?

Comment: try itextsharp library

Comment: What you tried so far ?? google it you can find many solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use iTextSharp for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are different libraries to accomplish this

1.[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

2.[PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)

3.[SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How to Export data as PDF format?
Below code is for export grid view data to PDF format

```
public void ExportToPdf(DataTable ExDataTable) //Datatable 
  {
    //Here set page size as A4

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

    try
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();

         //Set Font Properties for PDF File
        Font fnt = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 12);
        DataTable dt = ExDataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {

            PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
            PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;

            //Here we create PDF file tables

            for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {
                if (rows == 0)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                    {
                        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Columns[column].ColumnName.ToString(), fnt)));
                        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                    }
                }
                for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                    PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString(), fnt)));
                    PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                }
            }

            // Finally Add pdf table to the document 
            pdfDoc.Add(PdfTable);
        }

        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        //Set default file Name as current datetime
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".pdf");

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```