# Get the data in Word Excel and PDF format of datagridview using C#

Tags: c#

I have a one windows form and datagridview on it, I want to get the data of datagridview in Word, Excel or PDF format what is code please I am using C# in Visual Studio?

Comment: You can consider creating a RDLC report to put your data into, the ReportViewer control will give you flexibility to Print in numerous formats. Otherwise you can print the GridView using the following: This is the link where you can find the code sample to enable printing of GridView. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWinFormPrintDataGridView-75864c45#content This will give you a Print Dialog to select printer. You can use CutePdfWriter as the printer to print to a PDF. Here you can find CutePdfWriter : http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp

Comment: sounds like duplicate of  with additional need of excel and word http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979174/get-gridview-data-in-pdf-format-in-c-sharp-windows-form/14979584#14979584

Comment: Thanxxxxxxxxxx 1 question that i am new user when i click Vote Up then he says you require 15 reputation how can i increase my reputation?

Comment: You can just mark as answer :)

Comment: With 15+ points you can upvote it anytime.